# Timing for audio and subtitles

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I had a object

```
read={
    0:{
        all: 5880,
        from: 10680,
        to: 16560,
        text: "<div class='lrc'>It's been a long day without you my friend</div> "
    },
    1:{
        all: 5260,
        from: 17560,
        to: 22820,
        text: "<div class='lrc'>And I'll tell you all about it when I see you again  </div>"
    },
    2:{
        all: 5340,
        from: 23370,
        to: 28710,
        text: "<div class='lrc'>We've come a long way from where we began</div> "
    },
};
```

I want to timing subtitles and audio, and i did something in here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arb58700/1/).

When audio playing if time and time from in read variable is same it will be change color of text to red and show next line (look like karaoke animation). Now im stuck in timing step. Anybody can help?